# Probability of a noisy model

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have a model $y = x + n$. The law of $x$ and $n$(noise) are known. $y$ is the observation.

Thus I write:
$ p(y|x) = p_n(y-x)$.

Using the Bayes's rule I have:
$p(x|y) \propto p(y|x) p(x) $.

However, why could I not write:
$p(x|y) = p_n(y-x)$ ?

I know it is false but why ?

Comment: Your fourth line seems to ignore the $p(x)$ you have in your third line